# Neo4j java/traversal api -- deprecated methods

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal

I am writing some code for traversing neo4j database (Traversal API).
I am using the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>server-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-M02</version>
    </dependency>
```

IDE shows me that the following methods are deprecated:

```
   GraphDatabaseService.findNodesByLabelAndProperty()  
   GlobalGraphOperations.getAllNodesWithLabel()
```

I couldn't find any information on their replacement. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the javadocs aren't posted in an easy place online to google, you can find a [jar of the javadocs on maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.neo4j.doc%7Cneo4j-javadocs%7C2.2.0-M02%7Cpom).   Inside of that, just unzip the JAR and you get the full javadocs, which get to your answer.

`GraphDatabaseService.findNodesByLabelAndProperty()` is deprecated in favor of `GraphDatabaseService.findNodes(Label, String, Object)`

`GlobalGraphOperations.getAllNodesWithLabel()` is deprecated in favor of `GraphDatabaseService.findNodes(Label)`

Hope this helps.  For other libraries in other places, it's a trick worth remembering that a lot of library javadocs get packaged as separate JARs you can find by maven central, so if you need the javadocs for one very specific version or release (as was the case here) that's usually a go-to trick of mine, if google is frustrating me and only giving me javadocs for a different or incompatible version.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I like the most. First, direct solution. Then, how you can get there by yourself. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For both deprecated methods, use `GraphDatabaseService.findNodes()` instead, see http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M02/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#findNodes(org.neo4j.graphdb.Label).

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I think I saw the javadocs already. I'd swear I didn't see "Use findNodes(Label, String, Object)" before :)

Comment: @grubykarol if you just google the javadocs, you go to the wrong version, not 2.2.0-M02.  That's why you didn't find it when you went looking.   I'm glad Stefan posted a direct link...I was looking for that link for my answer and didn't find it, which is why I did it the convoluted JAR route.  :)